# Need advice for Implementing Caching in iPhone Programming, with Three20/ASIHTTPRequest or CoreData

Tags: iphone, core-data, three20, asihttprequest

I'm currently working on a Project that uses Three20 as the base framework, but I found out that ASIHTTPRequest handles Form Requests so easily so that's why I incorporated it in my Project.. And then I also found out that I need to cache my Session Key so that when my application terminates I can still check that my user is Logged in when the application launches back (and then again I'll be implementing it using basic Core Data)

As you can see there's a lot of Caching functionality in my Project, and I can't find out what is the best way, or which is the best way?

I don't know also how caching works in both Three20 and ASIHTTPRequest.. 
I really wanted to use their caching functionalities because I'll be caching also feeds and more

Comment: Are you asking how to cache the user credentials?

Comment: Is their another way for implementing caching for user credentials like using keychain? but I don't know how to do that.. if you have better ways, that would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to store user credentials, it's best to store them in the Keychain. You can do this via the [Keychain Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1) API. There are plenty of examples out there that show how to use this API. [Example 1](http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code). [Example 2](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html).